# How do we specify maven dependencies in pyspark

Tags: maven, apache-spark, pyspark

While starting spark-submit / pyspark, we do have an option of specifying the jar files using the `--jars` option. How can we specify maven dependencies in pyspark. Do we have to pass all the jars all the time when running a pyspark application or there is a cleaner way ?

Answer (score 4):

Another way I find very practical for testing/developing is when creating the SparkSession within the script, in particular by adding the `config` option and passing the Maven packages dependencies through `spark.jars.packages` in this way:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]")\
        .config('spark.jars.packages', 'groupId:artifactId:version')\
        .getOrCreate()
```

This will automatically download the specified dependencies (for more than one package dependency specify in a comma-separated fashion) from the Maven repository (so double check your internet connection).

At the same way any other Spark parameter listed [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#available-properties) can be passed to the Spark Session.

For the full list of Maven packages please refer to https://mvnrepository.com/

Comment: Is there a way to manage this using `pom.xml` & `mvn install` ?

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat were you able find any solution to manage the dependencies using pom.xml ?

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat @VGH sorry but I didn't use any `pom.xml` for my development as I used PySpark, sorry I can't help

Answer (score 2):

According to https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html there is an option to specify `--packages` in the form of a comma-delimited list of Maven coordinates.

```
./bin/spark-submit --packages my:awesome:package
```